# MVC Convert Base64 String to Image, but ... System.FormatException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, base64, form-data

My controller is getting an uploaded image in the request object in this code:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Upload()
{
    string fileName = Request.Form["FileName"];
    string description = Request.Form["Description"];
    string image = Request.Form["Image"];

    return fileName;
}
```

The value of image (at least the beginning of it) looks a lot like this:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEAYABgAAD/7gAOQWRvYmUAZAAAAAAB/...
```

I tried to convert using the following:

```
byte[] bImage = Convert.FromBase64String(image);
```

However, that gives the System.FormatException: "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

I get the feeling that the problem is that at least the start of the string isn't base64, but for all I know none of it is. Do I need to parse the string before decoding it? Am I missing something completely different?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you *may* just be able to strip out the `"data:image/jpeg;base64,"` part from the start. For example:

```
const string ExpectedImagePrefix = "data:image/jpeg;base64,";
...
if (image.StartsWith(ExpectedImagePrefix))
{
    string base64 = image.Substring(ExpectedImagePrefix.Length);
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    // Use the data
}
else
{
    // Not in the expected format
}
```

Of course you may want to make this somewhat less JPEG-specific, but I'd try that as a very first pass.

Comment: I need to accept jpg, gif, png, and bmp, which I suppose isn't so many to check for to handle it your way (assuming it works). However, I can't help but think that there's a correct way to parse that image. So many possible delimiters in that first 20 or so characters ... it can't be a coincidence.

Comment: Well, I think the format of `data:[content-type];[encoding],[data]` is pretty reasonable...

Comment: I just need to test it on Monday ... if it works I'll mark your answer

Comment: This actually worked great. After decoding, everything after the column was a valid image. Thanks for the help @Jon! I actually grabbed the mime-type, which I was basing off the filename, but I feel better grabbing it from there now.

Comment: string base64 = Regex.Replace(file, @"data:image\/(png|jpg|svg|gif)\;base64,", "");
    
    
       The code before will replace the text for png, svg, gif, jpg, files. Add more by adding |myType. Like this:

string base64 = Regex.Replace(file, @"data:image\/(png|jpg|svg|gif|myType)\;base64,", "");

Comment: How do you save the data into an image file ona server using C#?

Comment: @dave317: That entirely depends on the server - it's a very different question.

Answer (score 5):

The reason really is "data:image/jpeg;base64,", I'll suggest using this method for removing starting string from base64

```
var base64Content = image.Split(',')[1];
byte[] bImage = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Content);
```

This is Shortest solution and you don't have to use magic strings, or write a regex.

Comment: It's much better than the hardcoding of the header