# How to pass JavaScript value from View to Controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC project and I´m using Cropbox.js : jQuery Image Crop Plugin - http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-crop-image-plugin/ to crop an image of a user, but I cannot find how to get the cropped image to the controller.

JavaScript looks like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var options =
        {
            imageBox: '.imageBox',
            thumbBox: '.thumbBox',
            spinner: '.spinner',
            imgSrc: 'avatar.png'
        }
        var cropper;
        document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener('change', function () {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                options.imgSrc = e.target.result;
                cropper = new cropbox(options);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            this.files = [];
        })
        document.querySelector('#btnCrop').addEventListener('click', function () {
            var img = cropper.getAvatar()
            document.querySelector('.cropped').innerHTML += '<img id="Portrait" src="' + img + '">';
        })
        document.querySelector('#btnZoomIn').addEventListener('click', function () {
            cropper.zoomIn();
        })
        document.querySelector('#btnZoomOut').addEventListener('click', function () {
            cropper.zoomOut();
        })
    };
</script>
```

I tried to use the following in the controller, but since I´m requesting  the  file, I´m not sure if it can even work:

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["Portrait"];
```

Maybe it would be possible to store the img file from javascript to the model?

Comment: You should answer your own question with your fix and then select it as "answered" a day later. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend has solved it by adding following:

```
document.getElementById('avatarData').value = img;
```

To this part of the script:

```
    document.querySelector('#btnCrop').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var img = cropper.getAvatar()                
        document.querySelector('.cropped').innerHTML += '<img src="' + img + '">';             
        //new added
        document.getElementById('avatarData').value = img;
    })
```

Then used invisible input in View form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="avatarData" name="avatarData" value="">
```

Now I can catch it in controller:

```
var file = Request.Form["avatarData"];
```

And I´ll get:

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA..."
```

To work with this string, there is a very useful question & answer - [MVC Convert Base64 String to Image, but ... System.FormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032622/mvc-convert-base64-string-to-image-but-system-formatexception)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the jQuery Image Crop Plugin, but I think you'll need to do something like that:

Get the image's bytes, convert them to base64 and then send them to ViewController action using Ajax Post.

Answer (score 0):

i thing that you can use AjaxForm or HtmlForm and push it to any action. Then use `FormCollection` and watch your values. For example in my Captcha generator I override some action for filter:

```
   public class CaptchaValidator : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            RegisterViewModel model = filterContext.ActionParameters["model"] as RegisterViewModel;
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["Captcha"] == null || filterContext.HttpContext.Session["Captcha"].ToString() != model.Captcha)
            {
                filterContext.ActionParameters["captchaValid"] = false;
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.ActionParameters["captchaValid"] = true;
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

and use in your controller:

```
[CaptchaValidator]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, bool captchaValid)
```

I think that you can here change `bool captchaValid` to your `byte[]`.

I hope that it can help you :-)